# How to download data from AWS in python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and boto. The data I want to download is on AWS, and I have the access key and the secret key. My problem is I do not understand the approaches I found. For instance, this code:

```
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
def download_data_connect_s3(access_key, secret_key, region, bucket_name, key, local_path):
    conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id = access_key,\
        aws_secret_access_key = secret_key,\
        host='s3-{}.amazonaws.com'.format(region),\
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat()\
        )

    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    key = bucket.get_key(key)
    key.get_contents_to_filename(local_path)
    print('Downloaded File {} to {}'.format(key, local_path))

region = 'us-west-1'
access_key = # the key here
secret_key = # the secret key here
bucket_name = 'temp_name'
key = '<folder…/filename>' unique identifer
local_path = # local path

download_data_connect_s3(access_key, secret_key, region, bucket_name, key, local_path)
```

What I don't understand is the '`key' 'bucket_name'` and `'local path'`. What is `'key'` in comparison to access key and secret key?  I was not given a `'key'`. Also, is the `'bucket_name'` the name of the bucket on AWS (I was not provided with the bucket name); and local path the directory where I want to save the data?

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

`bucket_name` = name of your S3 bucket

`key` = is object key. It's full path of the file in side the bucket. (ex: you have a file named `a.txt` in folder `x`, so `key` = `x/a.txt`. Refer to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html)

`local_path` = where you want to save the data in local machine

Comment: Does this mean I need to create my own bucket to download the data to?

Comment: Do you own the file, or do you know where is file?

Comment: I don't know, I was only given access key and secret key, and was told that the data is on AWS. So the bucket name is the name of the bucket of the data I want to download, not the bucket on the console, right?

Comment: So, the bucket of the data is not exists in your AWS account?

Comment: In order to download file from S3, You need 3 things. Bucket of data, file path in s3 (object key) and your access key has permission to get object

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data is stored in Amazon S3.

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access Amazon S3.

To view the list of buckets in that account:

```
aws s3 ls
```

To view the contents of a bucket:

```
aws s3 ls bucket-name
```

To copy a file from a bucket to the current directory:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/filename.txt .
```

Or sync a whole folder:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name/folder/ local-folder/
```